# Two issues in Selenium - Dropdown Box and Alert Handling

Tags: java, selenium

I have two issues that I am facing with, after trying so many things, I couldn't figure it out. I need help from the community.

Issue 1#. I keep getting alerts in the middle of Execution which stops the execution. How do I handle those alerts and keep the execution of the program going?

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open

This error i get , i get an alert because i kept logging into the website using the same credentials a lot of times.

> User already logged in another machine.

So what i have done to handle this in the beginning of the login is :

```
try
    {
        //Login
        Login.Login_Module(driver , wait);
        //Set up Work Order Console.
        Login.WorkOrderConsole(driver , wait);
        //Read the Table
        Collector C1 = new Collector();
        C1.TableCollector(driver , wait);
    }
    catch(UnhandledAlertException e)
    {
        e.toString();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
```

If the Alert comes in , it handles the exception but the program cleanups and closes. How do i resume the program execution from the Exception break point.

---

Issue 2#. There is a dropdown box in the website , which i click. In the logs , i see the click being done on the dropdown box arrow , either dropdown box doesn't open up or the dropdown box doesn't stay open after the click.

How can solve this issue? i tried change Xpaths to all the elements around the dropdown box. but nothing works.

```
System.out.println("Im here");
Thread.sleep(1000);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
//Enter into the Work Order which is Assigned State.
WebElement Into_WO = driver.findElement(By.xpath(FXpath));              
Action DClick_WO = builder.doubleClick(Into_WO).build();
DClick_WO.perform();
//Change the Assigned State to In Progress State
WebElement Click_Status = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='WIN_3_7']/div/a")));
builder.moveToElement(Click_Status).click().build();
builder.perform();
System.out.println("After click");
System.exit(1);
```

Update 1# :
Here is the pastebin for the dropdown box div : https://pastebin.com/zragz8p4 
Here is the HTML code for the dropdown box :

```html
<div id="WIN_3_7" arid="7" artype="EnumSel" ardbn="Status" arlbox="0,4,104,17" class="df arfid7 ardbnStatus EnumSel" style="z-index:1928;top:173px; left:705px; width:262px; height:21px;" arwindowid="3">
<label id="label7" class="label f9" for="x-arid_WIN_3_7" style="top:4px; left:0px; width:104px; height:17px;">Status*</label><div class="selection" style="top:0px; left:105px; width:157px; height:21px;" arselmenu="[{v:&quot;Assigned&quot;},{v:&quot;Pending&quot;},{v:&quot;Waiting Approval&quot;},{v:&quot;Planning&quot;},{v:&quot;In Progress&quot;},{v:&quot;Completed&quot;},{v:&quot;Rejected&quot;},{v:&quot;Cancelled&quot;,l:&quot;Canceled&quot;},{v:&quot;Closed&quot;}]">
<input id="arid_WIN_3_7" type="text" class="text " readonly="" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:136px; height:21px;" title="In Progress">
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0px; left:136px; width:21px; height:21px;">
<img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**Update 2# :**

```
for(int i = 2; i<RowNum-1 ;i++)
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //String for Xpath
            int RowIndex=0;
            String f1 = "//*[@id='T302847900']/tbody/tr[";
            String f2 = "]";
            String FXpath = f1+i+f2;
            System.out.println(FXpath);
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //Getting the Row Elements in the Table
            List<WebElement> TrCollection = driver.findElements(By.xpath(FXpath));
            //TrCollections have all the Rows. - Go through all the rows.
            for(WebElement rowElement:TrCollection)
            {
                //Find all the columns in the current Row.
                List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount=rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                //Numbering the Columns every time a Row is done.
                int ColumnIndex=1;
                //Iterate Through Each Column and get the Text data from TD tag.
                for(WebElement colElement:TotalColumnCount)
                {
                    System.out.println("Row "+RowIndex+" Column "+ColumnIndex+" Data "+colElement.getText());
                    //If colElement.getText() has Assigned - Get click into the WO.
                    if(colElement.getText().equals("Pending"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Im here");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
                        //Enter into the Work Order which is Assigned State.
                        WebElement Into_WO = driver.findElement(By.xpath(FXpath));              
                        Action DClick_WO = builder.doubleClick(Into_WO).build();
                        DClick_WO.perform();

                        //Change the Assigned State to In Progress State
                        WebElement Click_Status = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='WIN_3_7']/div/a")));
                        Click_Status.click();
                        System.out.println("Inside Click");
                    }
                    ColumnIndex=ColumnIndex+1;
                }
                //Numbering the Next Row.
                RowIndex=RowIndex+1;
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
    //If the click is outside of the For Loops , it opens up.
    WebElement Click_Status = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='WIN_3_7']/div/a")));
    Click_Status.click();
    System.out.println("Outside Click");
}
```

Now when i put my Dropdown box click outside of the FOR loop , the dropdown box clicks and opens down revealing the options inside it , but when i put it inside the for loop , it doesn't open.

**Update 3#:**

When i put the click inside the For Loop , i get this error :

```
Element <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0px; left:136px; width:21px; height:21px;">...</a> is not clickable at point (986, 314). Other element would receive the click: <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.2; z-index: 100003; visibility: visible;"></div>
```

When i put the click outside the For Loop , it works and the dropdown opens without any error.

Comment: Please provide the HTML for the dropdown box!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: that's fine if drop down is not built using select and option tag , I assume it must be built using divs and spans

Comment: I have updated the Post to elaborate the issue. Sorry about that @DebanjanB

Comment: [Only ask a single question per question, click this text to find out why.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend breaking this post into two separate SO questions, that way you can elaborate on the issue #1.

For issue #2, you *should* be able to do what you just said to open the dropdown box, but in case that doesn't work, Selenium provides a class which deals specifically with dropdown boxes. See [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) for documentation regarding Selenium's `Select` class. Specifically, you can set the dropdown to be of whatever value/index/text using these 3 Select functions:

```
- selectByIndex(int index)
- selectByValue(java.lang.String value)
- selectByVisibleText(java.lang.String text)
```

You can retrieve the available options using the `getOptions()` method.

Keep in mind, when using `Select`'s `getAllSelectedOptions()` and `getFirstSelectedOption()` functions **in Python**, the functions look for and depend on the HTML having the `selected` attribute set when an option is selected.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, however I suspect the web element is not a Select as the wait statement is specifically looking for an anchor (link) to click.  Without the HTML code, though, we can't be sure.

Comment: True dat. I shall comment that above.

Comment: Thanks Musikreck , i will make it into two Seperate Questions. 

The Problem with using Select is , the dropdown box doesn't have Options tag. here is the paste bin of the html code for the dropdown box : https://pastebin.com/zragz8p4

Comment: Ya , sorry i didn't include that in the OP.

Comment: You can (and should) post that code in your original question.  I mean as actual text instead of pastebin.  Not everyone has access to pastebin.

Comment: Ya I have added the HTML also in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For your Issue#2 :

If the drop down is made of Divs and spans then you might wanna use this code :

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(by.xpath(" your locator"));
for(WebElement element : options){
 if(element.getText().equals(" your value from drop down")){
    element.click();
}
}
```

Note that , you will have to click on drop down first then this code would work for you.

As you have mentioned "click being done on the dropdown box arrow , either dropdown box doesn't open up or the dropdown box doesn't stay open after the click." That means you have to explicitly wait for drop down items to be in visible/presentable state.

Issue#1 :

You have to give more information about which kinda alert you are receiving frequently.

Comment: for that you would need to wait after clicking on drop box , use explicit wait in that case.

Comment: I just did this and still the Dropbox doesn't open up.

List<WebElement> options = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='WIN_3_7']/div/a")));
  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='WIN_3_7']/div/a"));
  for(WebElement element : options)
  {
   if(element.getText().equals("In Progress"))
  {
      element.click();
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for Issue 2#.

I need to wait for the loading circle to load up and finish.
I achieved that using :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@style='top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.2; z-index: 100005; visibility: visible;']")));
```

Once that is done , the Click Goes through on the Dropdown.